# delayed job doing nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

When I run rake:jobs work it shows that everything is running...

```
[Worker(host:Gregorys-MacBook-Air.local pid:17243)] Starting job worker
```

When I run without .delay the method runs fine...

```
@post.processimages
```

But when I run with .delay

```
@post.delay(queue: "processimages").processimages
```

Nothing happens...

I also have delayed_job_web installed and no jobs show in the queue

Any idea what can be causing this?